# Restriction on mobile number

Tags: java

I want a restriction on mobile numbers, where a user can give only 10 numbers and no symbols and alphabets should be allowed. The code that I use doesn't have any restrictions on entering alphabets.

```
mno=new TextField();
mno.setBounds(340, 460, 0, 0);
mno.setSize(90, 25);
mmess=new JLabel("Enter valid  mobile no.");
mmess.setBounds(450, 460, 0, 0);
mmess.setSize(300, 30);
mmess.setVisible(false);

mno.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        String input=mno.getText();
        Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("^\\d{10}$");
        Matcher m = patt.matcher(input);

        if (m.find()) {
            mmess.setVisible(true);
            mmess.setForeground(Color.RED);
        }
        else {
            mmess.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What's with the complete lack of indentation?

Answer (score 1):

Ref following code, here country code is also considered in mobile number, you can remove same if not required then use this regex  `"^\\+([0-9\\-]?){9,11}[0-9]$"` .

```
String regex = "^((\\+|00)(\\d{1,3})[\\s-]?)?(\\d{10})$";
String str = "+123-9854875847";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

if (m.matches()) {
    // actions to be taken
}
```

Comment: But this too doesn't restrict the user from entering alphabets.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`JFormattedTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html):

```
JFormattedTextField text = new JFormattedTextField(
        new MaskFormatter("###-####-####"));
```

This will allow only valid numbers to be entered in the first place, and the user does not have to guess the format. Here, `"###-####-####"` is just an example and should be replaced by whatever format you want those mobile numbers to have. ([see the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html))